# define two functions whose compositions are equal to identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, discrete-mathematics

Let B be the set $B = \{1,2,....n\}$ where n is a positive integer. Let C be the set of all bitstrings of length n and let Z be the set of all functions from B to $\{0,1\}$.

How do I find the two functions $x: C\rightarrow Z$ and $y: Z\rightarrow C$ such that $x \circ y = 1_Z$ and $y \circ x = 1_C$?

I have attempted to define the function x which is 1 if the LSB of the bitstring is 1 and 0 if the LSB is 0. I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: For the moment, focus on $Z$. An element of $Z$ is a function mapping $\{1,2,...n\} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$, how can you enumerate all such functions? If you were to pick one function in $Z$ and write an input/output table for it, what does the output column look like?

Comment: I'm not sure how to enumerate all such functions. But if we were to pick one function in Z, then it would simply have 0 and 1 as outputs with some conditons

Comment: Is the function that I talked about in the OP a valid function for mapping $C \rightarrow Z$? I'm not sure how to get the function for y, though.

Comment: Yes if you chart the outputs for an element of $Z$ you get an n-length column of 0 and 1, which looks a lot like an element of $C$. If I understand your definition of $x$, then it is not a valid mapping for $C \rightarrow Z$. $x$ is a function (of a bitstring) that outputs another function (in $Z$), where you are outputting 0 or 1.

Comment: What would be an example of a function that would be a valid mapping for C to Z?

Comment: Take an n-length bitstring, define the function $f(m)$ as the $m$'th bit in the bistring. For example $c = 010 \rightarrow f(m) : f(1) = 0, f(2) = 1, f(3) = 0$. Note that $c \in C; f \in Z$

Comment: So the function $f(m)$ would just output whatever the m'th bit is in the bitstring?

Comment: Yes, and $x(c) = f$

Comment: Okay I get that, but what about a function that maps Z to C?

Comment: You tell me, how can you take a function like $f$ and output a bitstring? And more relevant to your question, can you reverse the process we used to map $c \rightarrow f$ and now map $f \rightarrow c$? That is, can you invert $x$?

Comment: So a function $f(n)$ that outputs $f(n-1)$ until $f(0)$?

Answer (score 1):

A bitstring of length $n$ is by definition a function $b: \ [n]\to\{0,1\}$. It follows that the sets $C$ and $Z$ mentioned in the question coincide to begin with: $C=Z$. In other words: The maps $x$ and $y$ you are looking for are simply $x=y={\rm id\,}_C$.

I suggest you go back to your source and check what the authors really had in mind, e.g., proving that $C$ (or $Z$) is in bijective correspondence with the power set ${\cal P}\bigl([n]\bigr)$.

Comment: How does that answer my question?